# NodeMCU keeps hanging after random time

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have tried almost everything but my NodeMCU keeps hanging after random intervals, it usually stops working after 2 days, but well... I will describe it's behaviour, what I mean by hanging is that the server stops responding to the assigned static ip, if I restart my modem or the node it works again, but this device is meant to be working endlessly and shouldn't stop working even if it has been connected during one week, I have tested it a lot, it has worked for 2 days, for 3 days, once it worked for 4 days without any problem, but after reconnecting it in another place, hanged again after almost 2 days. I started to think that probably the problem it's related to NodeMCU. So please I would really appreciate any helpful suggestion like assigning ip through the modem or something that can help. Thanks in advance.

The NodeMCU is connected to a usb power hub (A regular android phone wall charger), and it controls a relay.

Here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "INFINITUM5607";
const char* password = "********";

int ledPin = 13; // GPIO13
int ledPin2 = 12; // GPIO13
int desconectado = 5;
int conectado = 4;
WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient client;

int counter = 0;
int count;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);

  pinMode(conectado, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(desconectado, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(desconectado, HIGH);

  connectWifi();  

  Serial.print(F("Setting static ip to : "));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());    

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");



}

void loop() {

  delay(200);

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(conectado, LOW);
    digitalWrite(desconectado, HIGH);
   connectWifi(); 
  }  

  // Check if a client has connected
  client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  count = 0;
while(!client.available()){
delay(1);
count++;
if ( count > 1000 )
{
Serial.println("Abandoned Client");
client.stop();
return;
}
}

//Serial.println("new client");
//  int t = millis();
//  while(!client.available()){
//  delay(1);
//  if (millis()-t>130) return;
//  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one

  // Match the request
  if (request.indexOf("/switch") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, !digitalRead(ledPin2));
    printSwitch();
  }else if (request.indexOf("/uno") != -1) {
    client.print("Canal 1 apagagado | Canal 2 encendido");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/dos") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 1 encendido | Canal 2 apagado");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/tres") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 1 apagado | Canal 2 apagado");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/cuatro") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 1 encendido | Canal 2 encendido");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/cinco") != -1){
    printIP();
  }else if (request.indexOf("/apagaruno") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 1 apagado");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/apagardos") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 2 apagado");    
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/prenderuno") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 1 encendido");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/prenderdos") != -1){
    client.print("Canal 2 encendido");
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  }else if (request.indexOf("/canaluno") != -1){

    if(digitalRead(ledPin) == HIGH) {    
      client.print("Off");
  } else {
    client.print("On");    
  }

  }else if (request.indexOf("/canaldos") != -1){

    if(digitalRead(ledPin2) == HIGH) {    
    client.print("Off");
  } else {
    client.print("On");
  }

  }

// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response  

  delay(1);  
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println(""); 
  client.stop();

}

void printSwitch(){ 

  if(digitalRead(ledPin) == LOW) {
    client.print("Canal 1 Encendido");
  } else {
    client.print("Canal 1 Apagado");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  if(digitalRead(ledPin2) == LOW) {
    client.print("Canal 2 Encendido");
  } else {
    client.print("Canal 2 Apagado");
  }
}

void printIP(){
  delay(100); 
  client.print(WiFi.localIP());
}

void connectWifi()
{
  Serial.print("Connecting to "+*ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
  }  

  // config static IP
  IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 66);
  IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);  
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  digitalWrite(conectado, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(desconectado, LOW);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected");
  Serial.println("");  

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
}//end connect
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the power source. If you're powering it via USB it is likely to malfunction over time, but if you use an external and stable power source you won't have that kind of problem.

Comment: What do you mean if I'm powering via usb, then how should I power it if I'm not using it's micro usb input? I'm using a wall power hub, like an android device charger.

Comment: I meant using a reliable external power source (which is probably what you're doing) as opposed to using your PC's USB port (as many people do, and it frequently results in that kind of problem). But even so, if you are getting it to work for 2 or 3 days straight, I would still check the power supply. To guarantee that is the problem, you can power it with a battery and see how it goes (just make sure to measure the current first and implement a sleep mode if necessary, otherwise it might run out of power too fast).

Comment: Is there the possibility of all this being a bug on the NodeMCU?